# Best way to develop between two different OSs

Tags: ruby, windows, macos, development-environment

I develop (for personal projects) on OSX at home: Ruby (looking into node), and a lot of basic web apps. I love OSX for development and find it to be a lot simpler to work in a dev environment and push from OSX to Ubuntu production...

The issue comes with my current job, where everyone uses Windows (not development related), but I'd like to do some work-related development with the same languages (Ruby/node/unix)...

What is a good way to work comfortably in two different development environments, sync (maybe github?) projects between the two easily, and focus minimally on "Hope this isn't a dependency/windows issue"?

I realize this is subjective and may have been asked elsewhere, but I'm looking for a TRIED method (not, "hey, try this") that is at minimum easy to sit down at one platform, do a simple sync, and get to work.

Comment: You'll have to account for platform specific issues irregardless of the synchronization method - hopefully it's "platform neutral", but .. (and if not, it might indicate certain pieces of code could be cleaned up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not opposed to using a virtual machine, you should consider [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with ethagnawl, [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) is the way to go for quick dev environment.
It works with Virtualbox, and allows you to use premade VM snapshots?, or "boxes" in this case.

An example premade box with RVM, Ruby, MySQL: [RWpreise64](http://railsware.github.com/dev_vagrant_box/)

This also works well with [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/) or [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) for "blueprinting" your server configurations and other infrastructure.  A Vagrant-Puppet/Chef combination is a great way to sandbox.

Here's a good introduction page: [Link](http://edvanbeinum.com/automate-your-development-environment-with-vagrant)

Note if you want a gui, you'll have to add the following to your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.boot_mode = :gui
```